# How can I get an hourly price feed from Tellor?

Tags: blockchain, oracles, polygon, tellor

I need an hourly/daily price feed on Polygon for two different coins, where can I get the queryID's and how do I know if they're supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there's an exchange/price for it, Tellor can submit it.

Head over to https://docs.tellor.io/tellor/integration/introduction , this is the official docs and can walk you through the correct way to read a value from one of our contracts.

Once you have your contract set up to read from tellor, you’ll need three things:

- The tellor address on your network:
  https://docs.tellor.io/tellor/integration/reference
- QueryData (the bytecode to tell the reporters what price it is)
- QueryID (the tellor ID that represents a certain price (hash of queryData))

For a price feed queryId, you can either find one or even make a new one if you’re the first person in the tellor ecosystem to request it.

- To check on current feeds or to generate a unique identifier, or queryId, for the asset/currency pair using [this tool](https://queryidbuilder.herokuapp.com/)

An example queryData is the encoded bytes of the request

```
abi.encode("SpotPrice",abi.encode("TRB","USD"))
```

which is:

> 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000953706f745072696365000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003747262000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000037573640000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

The queryID is simply the keccak256 hash of the queryData (0x5c13cd9c97dbb98f2429c101a2a8150e6c7a0ddaff6124ee176a3a411067ded0 )

Now that you have a queryId and queryData, you can use it to incentivize reporters to put that data on-chain.

Anyone can be staked reporter and place data on-chain regardless of whether it is requested or paid for. If you don’t want to report your own data though, you can request data using the Autopay contract.

To set up a data feed, you can use our automated tool:  https://fundafeed.herokuapp.com/

You can set up the contract to pay a reporter on a repeated basis (e.g. hourly or daily).  All you need to know is the tip amount, the interval (how often it’s reported (e.g. daily), and how close to that interval you need it (e.g. only submissions within 5 minutes of the new day are valid).

For full documentation on the Autopay contract check out: https://docs.tellor.io/tellor/integration/requesting-paying-for-data